# Transport Proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

I need to put a web proxy in place to log user activity at work after a recent incident. My first thought was Squid proxy but after some research it seems that https requests are a total nightmare. These days more sites are https than http so I need to log both. Can anyone recommend a proxy server or otherwise to pass all http and https requests through to log?

Thanks

Comment: what platform are you wanting to run the proxy on?  Sounds like you need a proxy with https inspection, there are several options.

Answer (score 1):

Squid can very well handle HTTP as well ass HTTPS traffic. How you should configure squid depends how you want the configure clients (I mean browser).

In general Squid proxy server can be configured to listen for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic on specific port (by default 3128) for squid and clients can be configured manually or using DHCP Option 252 + WPAD (Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol).

Alternately Squid can be configured in transparent mode intercepting the traffic on your network, in this case Squid will listen on different ports for HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

Shahnawaz